# Javascript(or maybe not) text editor with Image Upload functionality

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, fckeditor

I'm working in Ruby On Rails 2.3.8 and I need to use a text editor in which I could upload images.

Currently, I'm using TinyMCE, but doesn't have that feature. So, I've tried the TinyFCK, but I could not make it work (it uses PHP, so I'm not sure whether it will work or not in ruby on rails).

Does anybody know any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a [TinyMCE](https://github.com/sandipransing/rails_tiny_mce) `Rails` version with *Image Uploading*.

Answer (score 1):

So you've tried ckeditor? It's Javascript, not PHP. Some of the upload examples show PHP scripts to handle the browsing and uploading of images on the server but there's nothing to stop you creating these with Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at TinyFCK or other plugins described and evaluated [here](http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/cms/file-and-image-management-plugins-for-tinymce/).